# VBA Userform Combobox not populating on open

Tags: excel, vba

It been a while since I built a userform in Excel, so forgive me if this is something obvious. I have a userform containing a number of comboboxes. On opening the workbook, I populate them all with a list of reports stored in SQL, using the Workbook_Open macro.

However, when I close the userform and then reopen it, the comboboxes are empty. I that the way userforms work? Do you need to populate these boxes each time you launch the userform? I'm happy to do this but just wanted to check in case I'm missing a setting or a simple line of code.

Thanks

Comment: It's because the data is held in memory along with the form so when you close it that data is lost. Just move the same code to `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` of the form instead so that when the form open the data is retrieved again. Alternatively store the data on a worksheet or in a public variable and populate the comboboxes from there

Comment: Thanks Absinthe, makes sense

Comment: The data will also stay if you don't destroy the form (don't use `unload`). Instead, just hide it (`hide`).